# Prevent dialogbox being opened when using back button

Tags: javascript, xpages

On an xpage I have a script to prevent the back button to work to force users to use a cancel button:

```
if(history.forward() != null) { 
    self.location.reload() 
}
```

However, when the xpage is in 'edit mode' and a xe:dialog is open, the back button triggers the xe:dialog to open.

How can I disable this behavior?

Comment: Your users will hate you for breaking the back button. The reload opens the page in current state, so you need to add some state variable that prevents the dialog from reopening. Local store or URL

Comment: I hate myself already for breaking the back button :-?

Comment: I think the problem is in the way you open that dialog - it gets into browser history.

Comment: You can use a requestScope. variable - set it and only open the dialog if the condition matches.

Comment: @teleman Back button does not (by default) launch load/open scripts. It should work by disabling cache for that page in http header.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486022/xpages-handle-browser-back-button

Comment: Hi Frantisek, I set caching as disabled but that does not do the trick, when I close the dialog and refresh the page (F5) the dialog appears again

Comment: same problem, no solution https://xpagesandme.wordpress.com/2014/02/10/closed-dialog-box-reappears-when-clicking-on-refresh-button-in-browser/